# SharePoint 2013 Online JavaScript CSOM CEWP

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, client-object-model

I am in a need of some guidelines according developing in SharePoint 2013 Online. 
I want to learn developing on a sharepoint 2013 online site. Im using Content editor web parts and want to retrieve a list from my site, and now i wonder.

What to use to develop, javascript client object model, rest or something else?
im so confused!

Can i use the json or csom in the editor web parts?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Develop in SharePoint Online you should look at the SharePoint Hosted Apps: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx
Maybe with Napa: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj220038.aspx

If you persist on using Editor/ Script WebParts you may include jquery and user OData/REST it is very simple:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items", // Insert your listname here
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        cache:false,
        success: function (items) {
          var itemsArray = items.d.results;  //now you can do whatever you want with your items
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page of MSDN will help you learn how to write code to perform basic operations using the JavaScript client object model in SharePoint 2013. I always refer to this page when I'm developing SP 2013 app.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx